# How to select multiple ranges for a parameter WITHOUT first filling all other required parameters?

Tags: abap, sap-gui, dynpro

[image: The picture]

I'd want to be able to have multiple range selections for "Sales order no."

Problem is: when i press the button marked with green, i get the error "Fill in all required entry fields".

I put my main processing block at the START-OF-SELECTION event.

What to do to not have this happen? It seems to me that i should be able to add multiple selections without all the hassle of first filling every other mandatory field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With parameters/select-options set to OBLIGATORY, this won't work. I had the very same problem some time ago, and had no chance to fill the OBLIGATORY input parameters with useful values by default, so I did the following:

- Remove the OBLIGATORY option from all select-options and parameters
- Handle the check for obligatory input yourself in cases no F4,help, F1 help or the button next to any select option is pressed:

Code:

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON s_reswk.

IF sy-ucomm(1) <> '%' AND      " sel screen action request
   sy-ucomm(1) <> '_' AND      " scope option
   s_reswk IS INITIAL.         " Obligatory input missing
   MESSAGE text-e01 TYPE 'E'.  " Error message
ENDIF.
```

Comment: ...and while you're at it, use a message class. This will allow you to add a documentation text later on.

Comment: What is meant by `%` for selection screen action request and `_` for scope option?

Answer (score -2):

Here's what i found that completely reproduces the behavior set by the OBLIGATORY addition:

1:Take OUT the "OBLIGATORY" addition.

2:at PBO:

```
LOOP AT SCREEN.
  IF screen-name cs 'name-of-your-select-options-or-parameter'.
    screen-required = 2.
    MODIFY SCREEN.
  ENDIF.
```

3: at PAI:

```
if sscrfields-ucomm = 'ONLI'.
    if 'name of your select-option-or-parameter' is initial.
      clear sscrfields.
      message 'Fill in all required fields.'(009) type 'E'.
    endif.
  endif.
```

Notice the first if statement contains a 'cs' logical operator. That's cuz the name of your control will contain other weird stuff as well. For instance %_P_MATNR_%*SCREEN*%% (where your parameter was p_matnr).

Also, the declaration : `TABLES sscrfields.` is necessary.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. This way, you enforce entry of the required field when running the programm directly, but the user will be able to schedule it as a background job without entering the same parameter. Also, according to the documentation, screen-required takes either 0 or 1. Setting it to 2 might work now, but change its effect or stop to work altogether without further warning.